# How to return multiple table as jsonreult in asp.net MVC?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am getting multiple tables from store procedure result. I want to return this all table as the JsonResult in asp.Net MVC as a ajax response. but I am not getting response in `console.log(response);`. How to return multiple table as Jsonresult in MVC controller?

My debugger enter into method and getting data from store procedure and returning as a Json but after then in console I am getting error as bellow,

[image]

In ajax request, I have call `GetKYCListForUpdate` method as bellow,

```
 $('#KycListTable tbody').on('click', '.btn-edit', function (e) {
        var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();

        if (data.PartyBillId != null) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "@Url.Action("GetKYCListForUpdate", "KYCRegistration")",
                data: { id: data.PartyBillId },
                success: function (response) {
                    debugger
                    console.log(response);
                    var result = response.aaData;
                    if (result != null) {
                        $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                            console.log(item)
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

in asp.net MVC controller method as bellow,

```
  public JsonResult GetKYCListForUpdate(int id)
    {
        var AuthId = NC.ToInt(((Variables.scUserDetail)Session["UserDetail"]).AuthId);
        SqlConnection objsql = default(SqlConnection);
        objsql = new SqlConnection(Connect.GetConnStr(1));

        DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
        SqlCommand objSelectCmd = new SqlCommand();
        try
        {
            //objsql.ConnectionString = objsql;
            objsql.Open();
            objSelectCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            objSelectCmd.Connection = objsql;
            objSelectCmd.CommandText = "Sp_M35_01_GetKycListToEdit";
            objSelectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillPartyId", id);
            objSelectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuthId", AuthId);

            SqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objSelectCmd);
            objDataAdapter.Fill(dsData);


            for (int i = 0; i < dsData.Tables.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dsData.Tables[i].Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    result.Add(GetTableRows(dsData.Tables[i]));
                }
            }

   return Json(new { aaData = result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

public List<Dictionary<string, object>> GetTableRows(DataTable dtData)
    {
        List<Dictionary<string, object>>
        lstRows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
        Dictionary<string, object> dictRow = null;

        foreach (DataRow dr in dtData.Rows)
        {
            dictRow = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (DataColumn col in dtData.Columns)
            {
                dictRow.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
            }
            lstRows.Add(dictRow);
        }
        return lstRows;
    }
```

Comment: I think `var data = table.row($(this).parents('tr')).data();` need to be:- `var data = $(this).parent('tr').data();`

Comment: As per the error, the Action method 'GetKYCListForUpdate' is not getting ID parameter. check if data.PartyBillId is a valid num

Comment: As @TechGirl said, the error states that you are not sending the `id` oparameter to the controller. So check what you are sending.

Comment: @TechGirl I am sending id parameter to the method and getting value into debuger. Its execute store procedure and get data from store procedure then return as ajax. but after that on front end side i am getting this error.

Comment: @alka check my answer. From your screenshot I think you are posting back simultaneously to the ajax call running.

Answer (score 0):

A full page error like that, with the URL of your action in the address bar, indicates it's posting back and not using ajax (or possibly, executing both in parallel).

- Firstly check in your browser's console whether you have any script errors which are preventing the script from executing.
- Secondly check that your "click" event actually runs (a simple `alert` on the first line of it is the easiest way).
- Thirdly, if both the above tests pass, then you may need to write `e.preventDefault();` on the first line of the event handler, to prevent default postback behaviour. If your button is a "submit" button (either `<input type="submit"` or a `<button where either there's no type ("submit" is then default) or`type="submit"` is included) - because otherwise it will perform a standard postback as well as the ajax request. Once the postback gets going and leaves the original page then the ajax request is cancelled and the response doesn't get processed (because the page it was launched no longer exists in the browser, due to the postback).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved problem by modifying content as bellow,

I have put `jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;` line.

```
 public JsonResult GetKYCListForUpdate(int id)
{
    var AuthId = NC.ToInt(((Variables.scUserDetail)Session["UserDetail"]).AuthId);
    SqlConnection objsql = default(SqlConnection);
    objsql = new SqlConnection(Connect.GetConnStr(1));

    DataSet dsData = new DataSet();
    SqlCommand objSelectCmd = new SqlCommand();
    try
    {
        //objsql.ConnectionString = objsql;
        objsql.Open();
        objSelectCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        objSelectCmd.Connection = objsql;
        objSelectCmd.CommandText = "Sp_M35_01_GetKycListToEdit";
        objSelectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillPartyId", id);
        objSelectCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AuthId", AuthId);

        SqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
        objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objSelectCmd);
        objDataAdapter.Fill(dsData);


        for (int i = 0; i < dsData.Tables.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dsData.Tables[i].Rows.Count > 0)
            {

                result.Add(GetTableRows(dsData.Tables[i]));
            }
        }

 var jsonResult = Json(new{ result }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

            jsonResult.MaxJsonLength = int.MaxValue;
            return jsonResult;
}
```

and in web.config, I set the `maxJsonLength`

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="50000000"/>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
```